# Doctrine multiple where condition

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am Working with Doctrine 2.3 I am facing difficulty to design a Query for the below scenario.

```
SELECT * FROM source WHERE source_id ='10' or source_id ='100' or source_id ='30'
```

I did this for single Id selection but I am not sure how to do this.

```
$qry = $this->manager()->create()
        ->select('e')
        ->from($this->entity, 'e')
        ->where('e.id = :id');
```

Can some one help me in this?
If I get to know the working for the above query I will solve my other issues..
As Follows.

```
 SELECT * FROM source WHERE source_id ='10' and source_name ='test' and source_val ='30'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For first one change your where clause like,

```
->where('e.id IN (:ids)') 
->setParameter('ids', $ids)
```

Where `$ids = array('10','100','');`

And to use and condition for your second query it should be something like,

```
$qry = $this->manager()->create()
       ->select('e')
       ->from($this->entity, 'e')
       ->where('e.source_id = :id')
       ->andWhere('source_name=?', 'test')
       ->andWhere('source_val=?', '30')
```

Comment: I will try it and when I works I will accept your answer.. Thank you for your reply.. @Rikesh

Comment: can you help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917684/doctrine-xml-mapping-two-tables

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php     
$qry = $this->manager()->create()
    ->select('e')
    ->from($this->entity, 'e')
    ->where('e.id = ?', $eid)
    ->addWhere('source_id = ?', $source_id)
    ->addWhere('field = ?', $value)
    ->addWhereIn('id', array(1,2,3))
    ->addWhere('id = ? AND name = ?', array($id, $name));
?>
```

**OutPut**

SELECT e FROM TblName WHERE e.id = $eid AND  source_id = $source_id AND field = $value AND id IN (1,2,3) AND (id = $id AND name = $Name)

Comment: Is it `addWhere()` or `andWhere()` ?

Comment: @ToleaBivol It is andWhere() and to my knowledge there does not exist a function named addWhereIn() from symfony 2.3 - symfony 4.@ahmed Abumostafa.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Rikesh says use `IN` expression but here is another nice way to concatenate `AND` expressions

```
->where('e.foo = :foo', 'e.bar = :bar')
->setParameters([
   'foo' => $foo,
   'bar' => $bar,
])
```

**OutPut**

`... WHERE (e.foo = "foo" AND e.bar = "bar") ...`